# rails render action with that's params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, action, render

My route for pages in routes.rb

```
get ":slug", to: 'site#pages'
```

my actions in site_controller.rb

```
def pages
    render @page.page_template
end

def about
end

def contact
end

def content
end

def local_news
end

def global_news
    @newscasts = Newscast.published.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)
end
```

and it's my error :)
[image]

Not see `global_news` action my `@newscasts` parameter

Answer (score 1):

You need to define @newscasts inside pages method

```
 @newscasts = Newscast.published.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)
```

Or you can write this in your controller above your methods.

```
  before_action :global_news, only: [:pages]
```

Before action will run your global_news methods before every action defined inside only: in your case you can write (:pages) you can mention as many methods you want. If you remove only then global_news will run before every method.

Answer (score 0):

This cast an error because you are just rendering the `global_news`. With `render` you are not executing the controller action. So @newscast is never set.

You can either use a before filter as in the other answer or call the method manually, because I think you are doing something dynamically here, right?

for example

```
def pages
  global_news
  render @page.page_template
end
```

Comment: Can you propose alternative to me? How can I do other method?